# R purrr map show column names in output

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to run purrr `map` across vector inputs, and in the output i'd like the output columns to have meaningful names.

```
x <- c("a", "b")
y <- "end."

map_dfc(x, function(x) paste("pre ", x, y))

names(x) <- x
map_dfc(x, function(x) paste(x, y))
```

This is the output I expect, which has column names `a` and `b`:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# a      b     
# <chr>  <chr> 
# pre  a end. pre  b end.
```

Is there a way to avoid the need to run

```
names(x) <- x
```

i.e.

```
x <- c("a", "b")
y <- "end."

map_dfc(x, function(x) paste("pre ", x, y))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# a      b     
# <chr>  <chr>
```

yields the data.frame/tibble with column names already attached?

I use map alot and often forget if the input vector has names or not.

Comment: how about `set_names` ? `set_names(map_dfc(x, function(x) paste("pre ", x, y)), x)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `purrr` way is to use `set_names` as in the comments, (although correct `setNames` seems to be replaced by `set_names` in `purrr`):

```
map_dfc(set_names(x), function(x) paste("pre ", x, y))
```

With `set_names` you don't need to specify the new names if you use the default argument.

Answer (score 2):

One easy method is to have input elements named. This usually result in more consistent code.

```
library(purrr)
x <- setNames(c("a", "b"), nm = c("a", "b"))
# x <- setNames(nm = c("a", "b")) # this is short cut of above
y <- "end."
map_dfc(x, function(x) paste("pre ", x, y))
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @RonakShah's comment suggesting `setNames()`, you can handle this without `purrr::map()`:

```
paste("pre ", x, y) %>% 
  as.list() %>%
  as.data.frame(col.names = x, stringsAsFactors = F)
```