# replacing `.x` with column name after running `map::purrr()` function

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr

I run `lm()` for every column of a dataset with one of the column as the dependent variable, using `purrr:map()` function.

The results are almost perfect except for this - I want to replace `.x` in the results with the variable that i run `lm()` for.

The post [R purrr map show column names in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809045/r-purrr-map-show-column-names-in-output) is related but I want to avoid creating a function.

Below, are the codes using the mtcars dataset. I know, for example that `.x` for the first output refers to `$mpg`. I am not sure if `setNames()` will work.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
mod3 <- map(mtcars, ~ lm(mpg ~ .x, data = mtcars)) %>%
  map(~tidy(.x))
#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be
#> unreliable
mod3
#> $mpg
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   term         estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>   <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept) -5.02e-15  9.94e-16  -5.06e 0 0.0000198
#> 2 .x           1.00e+ 0  4.74e-17   2.11e16 0        
#> 
#> $cyl
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)    37.9      2.07      18.3  8.37e-18
#> 2 .x             -2.88     0.322     -8.92 6.11e-10
#> 
#> $disp
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  29.6      1.23        24.1  3.58e-21
#> 2 .x           -0.0412   0.00471     -8.75 9.38e-10
#> 
#> $hp
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  30.1       1.63       18.4  6.64e-18
#> 2 .x           -0.0682    0.0101     -6.74 1.79e- 7
#> 
#> $drat
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)    -7.52      5.48     -1.37 0.180    
#> 2 .x              7.68      1.51      5.10 0.0000178
#> 
#> $wt
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)    37.3      1.88      19.9  8.24e-19
#> 2 .x             -5.34     0.559     -9.56 1.29e-10
#> 
#> $qsec
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)    -5.11    10.0      -0.510  0.614 
#> 2 .x              1.41     0.559     2.53   0.0171
#> 
#> $vs
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)    16.6       1.08     15.4  8.85e-16
#> 2 .x              7.94      1.63      4.86 3.42e- 5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

names(mtcars)[-1] %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(~ lm(as.formula(paste0('mpg ~ ', .x)), data = mtcars)) %>% 
  map_dfr(., broom::tidy, .id = "variable")

#> # A tibble: 20 x 6
#>    variable term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>    <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 cyl      (Intercept)  37.9      2.07       18.3   8.37e-18
#>  2 cyl      cyl          -2.88     0.322      -8.92  6.11e-10
#>  3 disp     (Intercept)  29.6      1.23       24.1   3.58e-21
#>  4 disp     disp         -0.0412   0.00471    -8.75  9.38e-10
#>  5 hp       (Intercept)  30.1      1.63       18.4   6.64e-18
#>  6 hp       hp           -0.0682   0.0101     -6.74  1.79e- 7
#>  7 drat     (Intercept)  -7.52     5.48       -1.37  1.80e- 1
#>  8 drat     drat          7.68     1.51        5.10  1.78e- 5
#>  9 wt       (Intercept)  37.3      1.88       19.9   8.24e-19
#> 10 wt       wt           -5.34     0.559      -9.56  1.29e-10
#> 11 qsec     (Intercept)  -5.11    10.0        -0.510 6.14e- 1
#> 12 qsec     qsec          1.41     0.559       2.53  1.71e- 2
#> 13 vs       (Intercept)  16.6      1.08       15.4   8.85e-16
#> 14 vs       vs            7.94     1.63        4.86  3.42e- 5
#> 15 am       (Intercept)  17.1      1.12       15.2   1.13e-15
#> 16 am       am            7.24     1.76        4.11  2.85e- 4
#> 17 gear     (Intercept)   5.62     4.92        1.14  2.62e- 1
#> 18 gear     gear          3.92     1.31        3.00  5.40e- 3
#> 19 carb     (Intercept)  25.9      1.84       14.1   9.22e-15
#> 20 carb     carb         -2.06     0.569      -3.62  1.08e- 3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: This is spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use purrr::imap() like so:

```
mod3 <- map(mtcars, ~ lm(mpg ~ .x, data = mtcars)) %>%
  map(tidy) %>% 
  imap( ~   {.x[2, 1] <-  .y ; return(.x)}   )
```

imap sends two things to the function/ formula : .x the item and .y which is either the name of the item (name in this case) or the index.  I had to wrap everything in {} in this case to get the assignment to work

Comment: This works too but the curly braces make the codes slightly less straight forward